# a question on lmvt i guess...

Tags: mean-value-theorem

> let $f:[0,10]\to[10,20]$ be a continuous and twice differentiable function such that $f(0)=10$ and $f(10)=20$. Suppose $|f'(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in[0,10]$. Then, the value of $f"(5)$ is?

[This is my crude way of doing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxsRg.jpg)

I thought of it like this, the maximum function that can increase is with slope 1. So if it increases anywhere at less than slope 1 then at some other point it has to increase with a slope greater than 1 for it to reach the point (10,20) so it has to be linear fun. with slope 1 everywhere and therefore f"(x)=0 but can someone give me some formal proof of it?

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your thinking is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$20=f(10)=f(0)+\int_0^{10}f'(t)dt\leq 10+10=20$ since $f'(t) \leq 1$ for all $t$. This inequality forces $f'(t)$ to be $1$ for all $t$. [If $f'(t)<1$ for some $t$ then $f'(t)<1$ in some open interval contained in $[0,10]$ and this forces $\int_0^{1} f'(t)dt$ to be strictly smaller than $10$].   Hence,  $f'(5)=1$. Also, $f(5)=f(0)+\int_0^{5} 1dt=15$.

Comment: does this have nothing to do with lmvt?

Comment: thank you so much by the way